# easiest way to send firebase push notification from client site in react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification

I am new to react native and I am stuck to send push notification from client side. i have FCM token of every user but need to send a notification to specific user. if you want more clarity please comment and let me know the solution of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your problem and I have a solution for you. I am already doing it and here's my code.

```
export const sendPushNotification = async (token, title, body,) => {
//console.log("token==>", token);

const FIREBASE_API_KEY ="<your firebase cloud messaging server key>"

const message = {
  registration_ids: [token],
  notification: {
    title: title,
    body: body,
    vibrate: 1,
    sound: 1,
    show_in_foreground: true,
    priority: "high",
    content_available: true
  },
};

let headers = new Headers({
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  Authorization: "key=" + FIREBASE_API_KEY
});

let response = await fetch("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", {
  method: "POST",
  headers,
  body: JSON.stringify(message)
});
   // console.log("=><*", response);
   response = await response.json();
  //  console.log("=><*", response);
};
```

you can use this function like this

```
sendPushNotification(
    FCMToken,
    'title of message',
    `this is body of message`,
  );
```

hope it will worked on your side